# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my project I am Uploading some files SQL Server, when the files are uploaded in the table **Table1** another function will check that Table **Table1** for files and inserts the Random Number or Characters into a table **Table2** by getting the Random Numbers or Characters from another function which generates and returns it as string, now my problem is that the Files are correctly Uploading and saving in the **Table1** but when **Table1** is inserted with files the other function which inserts Random Numbers / Character initiates but throws the Exception My Code is,

```
 public class Upload : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Expires = -1;

    try
    {
        HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

        string savepath = "";
        string tempPath = "";
        tempPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
        savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath);
        string filename = postedFile.FileName;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        string contenttype = String.Empty;
        switch (ext)
        {

            case ".doc":

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

                break;
            case ".docx":

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

                break;

            case ".pdf":

                contenttype = "application/pdf";

                break;

        }

        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        byte[] b = ReadFile(postedFile);
        ExamManagement.SP.QUESTIONPAPER_SP_UPLOAD(filename, contenttype,b).Execute();
        trigger();

    }

    catch (SqlException exp)
    {
        if (exp.Message.Contains("PK_answerkey"))
        {
            context.Response.Write("File Already Uploaded.....");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }


}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
private byte[] ReadFile(HttpPostedFile fObj2)
{
    byte[] data = new Byte[fObj2.ContentLength];
    fObj2.InputStream.Read(data, 0, fObj2.ContentLength);
    return data;
}
protected void ClientMessaging(string msg)
{
    String script = String.Format("alert('{0}');", msg);
    Anthem.Manager.IncludePageScripts = true;

}
protected void trigger()
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = ExamManagement.SP.Questionpaper_SP_Selectall().GetDataSet();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string a = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            string b = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            string c = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            ExamManagement.SP.Passkey_insert(a, b, c).Execute();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw; **// Exception Was Thrown Here**
    }



}
public static string RandomNumberGenerator(int length)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator rng = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

    char[] chars = new char[length];

    //based on your requirment you can take only alphabets or number 
    string validChars = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXzZ";

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);

        Random rnd = new Random(bytes[0]);

        chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(0, 61)];
    }

    return (new string(chars));
}
```

}
Can Some Body Help me out...
Thanks in Advance....
Error comes in this Part of the Code...

```
     protected void trigger()
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = ExamManagement.SP.Questionpaper_SP_Selectall().GetDataSet();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string a = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            string b = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            string c = RandomNumberGenerator(4);
            ExamManagement.SP.Passkey_insert(a, b, c).Execute();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw; **// Exception Was Thrown Here**
    }



}
public static string RandomNumberGenerator(int length)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator rng = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

    char[] chars = new char[length];

    //based on your requirment you can take only alphabets or number 
    string validChars = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXzZ";

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);

        Random rnd = new Random(bytes[0]);

        chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(0, 61)];
    }

    return (new string(chars));
}
```

The Passkey_insert SP is,

```
   Create Procedure Passkey_insert
    (
     @red varchar(100),
     @green varchar(100),
     @blue varchar(100)
     )
   as
 BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY
 Insert into Passkeys(Red,Green,Blue) values (@red,@green,@blue)
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH                
 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0                
 ROLLBACK                
 DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int                
 SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),                
 @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()                
 RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)                
 END CATCH 
 END
```

Comment: Code posted is too huge. Can you post the relevant part only. Plus, provide the stack trace.

Comment: which line is giving you error?

Comment: Keeping the solution aside - the catch block which rethrows the exception without doing anything is kind of useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `validChars` length is 50 yet here you random number from 0 to 61:

```
chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(0, 61)];
```

change it to:

```
chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(0, 51)];
```

Comment: I had Changed it but another Exception **String or binary data would be truncated.** was thrown

Comment: Where was it thrown? It could happen because you tried to insert more data into database column than it could hold.

Comment: What column lengths `Passkeys` table has for columns `Red,Green,Blue`?

Comment: This is script of PassKey table it does have red,green and blue **/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS ******/ SELECT TOP 1000 [Red] ,[Green] ,[Blue] FROM [Eval].[dbo].[Passkeys]**

Comment: What I meant is: http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/1238/dbms.png for your columns in that table.

Comment: the **Red** column is **varchar(100),null**, **Green** column is **varchar(100),null** & **Blue** column is **varchar(100),null**

Comment: The only reason for that error is that length of any string (a, b, c) returned from `RandomNumberGenerator` is larger than 100. Otherwise I do not see any reason for that exception.

Comment: Solved now.... There is no error in the Passkey_insert and its Parameters, the error is A trigger will be initiated and inserts with Red+Green+Blue into a table when the Passkeys table get the Value inserted that Red+green+Blue field length is small so that I got that Exception

Comment: That is why I always stay away from triggers :). Created it worked and good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You set validChars to an array of 50 chars then use rnd.Next(0, 61) to get an index for the array.  By definition, it might exceed the length of validChars.

Change the line:

```
chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(0, 61)];
```

...to instead be:

```
chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(0, validChars.Length)];
```

(note that the Next() function's 2nd parameter is exclusive, therefore you'll be using a range of 0 through 49 with this, matching your array)

Comment: I had Changed it but another Exception **String or binary data would be truncated.** was thrown

Comment: If Passkey_insert() is inserting to a database, do all three parameters meet criteria?  In other words, do "a", "b", and "c" all being 4 chars in length violate the insert?  Does the insert function require more or less parameters?

Comment: I'm going to have to know more about Passkey_insert() then, because that error is SQL related, and as such it's about the insert, not the RandomNumberGenerator() method.

Answer (score 0):

Your validChar array is only 50 chars wide, yet you are using validChars[rnd.Next(0, 61)] to lookup a char character

change

```
chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(0, 61)];
```

to

```
chars[i] = validChars[rnd.Next(0, validChars.Length)];
```

Comment: I had Changed it but another Exception **String or binary data would be truncated.** was thrown

Comment: That sounds like an SQL error, are you sure your Passkey_Insert stored procedure is working correctly or you are passing strings which are too long to it.

Comment: I had felt that also and Chaged my field length from **varchar(15)** to **varchar(100)** but still problem presists two hours back it was inserting correctly now only the problem occurs...

Comment: Are the columns types/and sizes correct in the PassKey table?